# TikZ: Using current length inside scope environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, lengths

Following this answer: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/107530), I'm using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to draw over an image. This (inside the `scope` environment) reescales the coordinates of both the x and y axis to match the borders of the image (y = 0 is the lower border and y = 1 the upper border of the image). I want to use these new reescaled lengths in a command like 
`\node[inner sep = 0.5]`

The 0.5 will default to 0.5pt, while I may want to use the lengths in which the x or the y axis are given. Is there any simple way in which I can obtain this length and then use it in a node command? I'm looking for something that would look as `\node[inner xsep = \xlength, inner ysep = \ylength]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\path(1,1);\pgfgetlastxy{\xlength}{\ylength}
```

inside the scope.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \path(1,1);\pgfgetlastxy{\xlength}{\ylength}
    \node[
        inner xsep=.25*\xlength,
        inner ysep=.25*\ylength,
        draw=green,
        line width=4mm,
        fill=orange,
        opacity=.2
    ] at (.25,.25){};
    \node[
        inner xsep=.5*\xlength,
        inner ysep=.5*\ylength,
        draw=purple,
        line width=4mm,
        opacity=.2
    ] at (.5,.5){};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: From the docs:
`\pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}`
"Stores the most recent used (x,y) coordinates into two macros"